# Column does not exist when left_joining local data frame to remote postgresql table with dplyr.

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I have a local data frame called `tox` which contains two columns, `chem_code` and `LD50`. I want to (dplyr) left_join `tox` into a postgresql table called `usage` which has columns `year`, `location`, `lbs`, `area`, and `chem_code` using `chem_code` as the join key. I'm doing the following, setting `copy = TRUE` as per the dplyr documentation:

```
   library(dplyr)
   tox <- load("~/dir/tox.csv")
   con <- src_postgres(dbname = "etc", 
                       host = "etc.com", 
                       user = "etc")
   usage <- tbl(con, dplyr::sql("SELECT * FROM data.table1"))
   usage_tox <- left_join(usage, tox, by = "chem_code", copy = TRUE)
```

However, when I attempt to do further dplyr operations using columns originating in `tox`, such as:

```
   usage_tox <- usage_tox %>%
                ## convert to grams then divide by LD50
                mutate(lethal_doses = 453.592 * lbs / LD50)
```

and then:

```
   usage_tox <- collect(usage_tox)
```

I get the error:

```
   Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...): RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "LD50" does not exist
```

Which I find bizarre, because when I examine `usage_tox` prior to mutating:

```
    head(usage_tox)
    chem_code   year    location    lbs     area       LD50
       231     1995   04M20N01E01   420.32  266.3       100 
       231     1995   04M20N01E01   120     163         100 
       253     1995   04M20N01E01   173.686 185        0.059
```

`LD50` appears to be there.

Am I asking dplyr to do something it can't do? Thank you in advance.